# javascript variable parsing by php regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse some javascript variables using PHP.

Random website: (**not my website**)

```
//.... content ...
    function(response) {
        if (response) {
            var data = { id: "fka1q021", action: "post", date: "today" };
        }
        //.....
```

---

```
$url = 'www.website.com';
$content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url));
    preg_match_all('/var data = { id: "(.*?)", action: "post", date: "today" };/', $content, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

I want to get value of **id** which is **fka1q021**

How can I get it? Thanks

Comment: @moonwave99 Plain `json_decode` only understands JSON, not JavaScript object literals.

Comment: @moonwave99 - I can't use json, I don't have access to the site

Comment: You can use json_decode on a string, that's the point. The only problem is to reach your variable correctly with your preg expression. You need to preg "#data = {([^}]*)}#" (didn't tried)

Comment: @PierreGranger: The problem is the string is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah 'cause of id:"value" instead of "id":"value", bad luck. '#id: "[^"]*"#' ? preg_match("##Ui") instead of preg_match_all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`.  Then, the `$matches` array will contain the entire matched expression as its 0th element, and the match within your parenthesized sub-expression as its 1st element.  That 1st element is the `id` you're looking for.

So, try:

```
preg_match('/var data = { id: "(.*?)", action: "post", date: "today" };/', $content, $matches);
```

Here is full example code:

```
<?php

$content = <<<ENDOFCONTENT
//.... content ...
  function(response) {
    if (response) {
      var data = { id: "fka1q021", action: "post", date: "today" };
    }
//.....
ENDOFCONTENT;

preg_match('/var data = { id: "(.*?)", action: "post", date: "today" };/', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
print "id = " . $matches[1] . "\n";
```

Here is resulting output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => var data = { id: "fka1q021", action: "post", date: "today" };
    [1] => fka1q021
)
id = fka1q021
```

Comment: Array is empty... Output: Array ( )

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the input content (sample) that you provided, along with my resulting output.  It shows that it works.  Are you sure that `$content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url));` does what you think it does?  It may be helpful for you to print out `$content` immediately after that line of your code, to ensure that you have the full content of the file.

Comment: [CBroe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) does have a point regarding `htmlspecialchars`.  His answer gets an up-vote from me.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting anything with your regular expression, because you are applying `htmlspecialchars` to the content you are reading – and that replaces `"` with `&quot;`, so your expression does not find the `"` you have in there.

Just remove `htmlspecialchars`, and your pattern will match.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side and PHP is server side, so all the PHP will have executed before the Javascript can run. See this question: [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your doing is legit... JS ans PHP doesn't execute at the same time and in the same place. Maybe you got this after an ajax call ?

Anyway, analysing a JS data with php can be done with json_decode. I think your problem here will be that json_decode won't understand {id:"value"}, he needs {"id":"value"} instead...

```
if ( preg_match("#data = ({[^}]*})#",$data,$matches) )
    json_decode($matches[1]) ;
```

For example,

```
print_r(json_decode('{"id":"fka1q021","action":"post","date":"today"}') );
```

Render a php object :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => fka1q021
    [action] => post
    [date] => today
)
```

Comment: He's trying to parse a JavaScript object in PHP.  It's not written as valid JSON, so `json_decode` won't work, unless he can "fix" the string.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regex is

```
(?:id:\s(\".*?\"))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5IapY-bLOR1Ccr5E)

then the id will be in capture group 1.

Let me know if you need a more complex regex. And if so, provide more info.